# passing values from a table to a tab bar controller

Tags: ios5, xcode4

I am working on a navigation based iPhone app.  in one point in this app there is a table, which each cell will lead to the same tab bar controller but the data in that tab bar controller will depend on which cell was tapped.

i'm using storyboard to implement this app. But my problem is not being able to pass the value to the tab bar controller. i'm trying segue and other methods, but  its not working with me, and i can't find much of resources in how to accomplish this.

i only need to pass a string so the tab bar controller and each view in the tab bar will  know which cell was tapped.

Thanks.